# Sending data from one component to another in Angular (CLOSED)

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am currently trying to send data (a simple string that I got in a variable) from one component to another. Usually, I would use an EventEmitter but in my case it wouldn't work (or so I believe after trying it out!). This is due to the fact that the component that originally holds the data is not called on html using the  tag. It is implemented in another way: by calling the class!

This is what you need from my code :

**The first component which holds the email string value**

```
  export class EditEmailCaliComponent {
    @Output('caliConfirmationEmail')email = new EventEmitter<string>();

    form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      emailAddress: new FormControl(''),
    });

    constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditEmailCaliComponent>, @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: boolean) {}

    saveEmail(){
      this.email.emit(this.form.controls.emailAddress.value);
      console.log('email is ' + this.form.controls.emailAddress.value);
    }
  }
```

**The second component. I am trying to use the trySave() method in order to output the email to the console**

```
  export class CaliDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  name = '';
  scannerList: string[] = [];
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['scanners'];
  usedEmail: string[] = [];
  displayedColumns2: string[] = ['email'];

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<CaliDialogComponent>,
              @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: boolean,
              private userService: UserService,
              private dialog: MatDialog) {
    this.data = true;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadCali();
    this.loadEmail();
  }

  loadCali(): void {
    this.userService.loadCali().subscribe((table) => {
      this.scannerList = table;
    });
  }

  loadEmail(): void {
    this.userService.getEmail().subscribe((answer) => {
      this.usedEmail = [];
      this.usedEmail.push(answer.response);
    });
  }

  onNoClick(): void {
    this.data = false;
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  editCali(element: string): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditCaliDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.form.patchValue({
      scannerName: element,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result !== element && result !== undefined && result !== '') {
        this.userService.updateCali(element, result).subscribe(() => {
          this.loadCali();
        });
      }
    });
  }
  editEmail(element: string): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditEmailCaliComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    });

    dialogRef.componentInstance.form.patchValue({
      emailAddress: element,
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result !== element && result !== undefined && result !== '') {
        // this.userService.updateEmail(element, result).subscribe(() => { // Update the email address stored on the database.
        //    // Send the value to the modified one and send it to server...
        // });
      }
    });
  }

  createCali(): void {
    if (this.name === '') { return; }
    this.userService.createCali(this.name).subscribe(() => {});
  }

  trySave(email): void{
    console.log('email is + ' + email.this.form.controls.emailAddress.value);
  }

  deleteCali(element: string): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DeleteDialogComponent, {
      width: '250px',
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      if (result) {
        this.userService.deleteCali(element).subscribe(() => {
          this.loadCali();
        });
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**The Html part for the email box**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="usedEmail" class="mat-elevation-z8 tabElement">
    <app-edit-email-cali (caliConfirmationEmail)="trySave($event)"></app-edit-email-cali>

    <ng-container matColumnDef="email">
          <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Receiving Email</th>
          <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element
  ">
              <span class="floatLeft">{{element}}</span>
              <button mat-icon-button title="Edit" (click)="editEmail(element)" class="btn">
                  <mat-icon color="primary">edit</mat-icon>
              </button>
          </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns2"></tr>
      <tr
          mat-row
          *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns2;"
      ></tr>
  </table>
```

If you need anything else, I will be happy to provide it!

**UPDATE --> FIXED**
I got it working, thank you everyone!

Comment: Take a look here... https://fireship.io/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/ ... it might help.

Comment: @Nader I already did research (this was a part of it) and tried many ways but nothing seams to work. Thank you for trying!

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is here:

```
trySave(email): void{
  console.log('email is + ' + email.this.form.controls.emailAddress.value);
}
```

try to change getting of value to:

```
trySave(email): void{
  console.log('email is + ' + email);
}
```

P.S. If this shouldn't work, provide a code where triggers saveEmail function.

Comment: I tried to put a simple console.log('test') in the trySave() function and it was never output. I'm guessing my trySave() function is never called (it didn't stop at any breakpoint). I can't think of any other way to call it...

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this...

In your first component:

```js
@Output() email = new EventEmitter<string>();

...

saveEmail(){
  this.email.emit("your string or any variable here");
}
```

Second (parent) component template:

```html
<app-edit-email-cali (email)="trySave($event)"></app-edit-email-cali>
```

Second (parent) component ts:

```js
trySave(event: string){
  console.log(event)
...
}
```

Comment: I tried to put a simple console.log('test') in the trySave() function and it was never output. I'm guessing my trySave() function is never called (it didn't stop at any breakpoint). I can't think of any other way to call it...

Comment: I tried to improve the answer, but honestly this should work... This is how you emit any object from a child to a parent in Angular. If you create a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/), I'll take a look for you.

Comment: the thing is that since the app-edit-email-cali is not called using an html tag, I can't find a way to even get the (email)="trySave($event)" to be read

Comment: You got it working? What was the solution?

Comment: to be honest I just resorted to sending the data to the database and then reload the specific component with a delay of 1 second (to give time to the db to get updated).

Comment: You could just use a service to cache the data... and update the cache after making a request to the db.  This way you don't have to refresh the page, but rather push the cache to a Subject. Either that or use NgRX, if there is a lot of state like that to manage in your application. I was under the impression this was about a Child -> Parent relation. If you want to communicate between unrelated components (siblings, or deeply nested or more than 2 components), a shared data service is the way to go.

Comment: Well I don't reload the page, I just reload the small component so it runs really smoothly!